# What does `setq-local` do, and when should I use it?

Tags: buffer-local, defvar, defvar-local

I'm not quite clear on all the variations of buffer-local variables, even
after reading all the doc and a bunch of postings here on SX.

Here's a summary of my understandings:

`(defvar foo ..)` declares a dynamic variable for the file. But the
variable is (1) not known to other files unless they include a `defvar`
statement as well, and (2) the variable is global in scope, not buffer
local.

`(make-variable-buffer-local foo)` after the `defvar` above tells the
compiler and everyone else that the variable foo is to be treated as
buffer-local everywhere it is set, when it is set. So this pattern is
good style for declaring a buffer-local variable, putting both statements
back-to-back in the file.

```el
(defvar xxx ...)                    ;declare xxx with global scope
(make-variable-buffer-local 'xxx)   ;but now make it buffer-local everywhere
```

For convenience, the `(defvar-local xxx ...)` form can be used as one
line, in place of the two lines above:

```el
(defvar-local xxx ...)       ;make xxx buffer local everywhere
```

Once declared as above, the variable xxx can be used like any other
variable in setq statements.

If I just want to have a single instance of a buffer-local variable that
is already a global dynamic variable, I would use the following
declarations. The first one declares the global-scope dynamic variable,
and the second statement makes just one instance of a buffer-local
version of that variable, in the current buffer:

```el
(defvar xxx ...)             ;declare xxx with global scope
(make-local-variable 'xxx)   ;make xxx local in this buffer only
```

---

Now for my explict questions (all the above were implicit questions on
whether my understanding is correct).

When setting the value of variables, I can use `setq` or
`setq-local`. When should `setq-local` be used? Why?

What happens if I use `setq-local` on buffer-local vars, or
non-buffer-local vars?

Is `setq-local` required for a `defvar-local` declared variable?

Will `setq-local` on a normal `defvar` declared variable turn it into a
buffer-local variable? (In other words, is `setq-local` somehow the
equivalent of a `(make-variable-local xxx)` declaration?

Comment: Thanks for the extra labor Scott. I will put in the extra backquotes from here on in.

Comment: `(setq-local VAR VALUE)` is just shorthand for `(set (make-local-variable VAR) VALUE)`, which was (and still is) a common idiom.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most of your assumptions are close.  I'll mention a few later.  But, first the main question.

The form `setq-local` is merely a convenience, it is the same as doing `make-local-variable` followed by `setq`.  If you had done a <kbd>C-h f setq-local</kbd> to see the documentation and clicked through to the source you might have seen this.  That's how I verified my first impression.  The code is a little obscure, though, since it is optimizing on things like the fact that `make-local-variable` actually returns the variable itself.  Using `setq-local` is a way to point out the localness in some code, so that others know the code can't be playing with the global value of the variable.  You do *not* need to use it to access local variables.  Any variable can be made buffer-local and that will affect all code that touches the variable (except if it goes out of its way to get the global copy with `setq-default` or similar).

That's the primary answer.  Now, there are a few things in your background that are a little off.  Since you asked about that, I'll address some things.

The first is "not known to other files".  This isn't really true.  Any code can reference any global variable (that's why they are called "global") without including the `defvar` (and <kbd>C-h f defvar</kbd> says so).  In fact, there should only be **one** main `defvar` (with docstring and default value) for each global variable.  A `defvar` with just the variable name can be used to suppress a byte-compiler warning.  Emacs only uses the value from the first one it sees¹ and the docstring from the last one.  If there are multiple `defvar`s with value/docstring they can be confusing to people reading the code.  And the order of loading files will matter.

Some variables are *intended* to be used only as buffer-local and those are the ones that use `defvar-local` (or the two part `defvar` / `make-variable-buffer-local` which it is short for, mostly in older code before the short form was added).  This makes it be buffer-local in all buffers.  For some variables, their primary use is not buffer-local, but for some reason you may want one buffer to have a different value.  That's when you use `make-local-variable`, usually in some buffer setup code almost never right after a `defvar`.

And as a general thing, there are two purposes to the `defvar` forms.  One is to have some documentation, so that <kbd>C-h v</kbd> can be used by others to know what the variable is for.  The second is to declare a "default" value, so that the variable is always set.  The declaration of the default value only affects the global (or default) instance of a variable, and is only used if that instance is not already set to something.  That means that if you `setq` some variable and then include the file with the `defvar` (e.g. through a `require`), the defvar will not change the value.

¹  <sub>More precisely, `defvar` doesn't modify the value of the variable if it's already set (it does set the docstring however); this is meant so that the user's init file can do `(setq some-variable)` before a package is loaded to override the package's default value.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer, it helps a lot. When I used the phrase "not known to other files" I was thinking of free variable warnings because those other files will think the variable is free unless I add a defvar to them too. I like your statement that `set-local` tells readers that a local var is being set. Anything I can do to improve readability of my code is good! PS. I will try to click through to the source more often; at my current level of development, it often doesn't really get at the semantics... :-)

Comment: "there should only be one `defvar` for each global variable" isn't strictly correct -- there are situations when `(defvar VARNAME)` *without* a value should be declared, independently of the proper definition (with initial value and ideally a docstring) of that VARNAME.

Comment: Note also that `setq-local` and `defvar-local` were only introduced in Emacs 24.3.

Comment: @phils, could you please identify the situations that you speak of, where `(defvar varname)` should be declared _without_ a value? I'm thinking that's what Drew suggested in another thread when I was asking how to get rid of free variable warnings in my files for globals I had declared elsewhere. I do that now. Is that the situation that you speak of?

Comment: Avoiding byte-compilation warnings is one reason, yes (see `C-h i g (elisp) Warning Tips`). The other is for libraries using lexical-binding, to ensure (if necessary) that a variable is dynamically bound rather than lexically bound.

Comment: @phils is right.  That's a use for `defvar` with only the variable, one that I'd forgotten (because the other LISP I use has a different name for that case).  I think I'll edit it into my answer...

Comment: Isnt it set after make-local eg (set (make-local-variable 'tab-width) 8)